# Can't open JFoenix-window

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Whenever I try to open my JFoenix programm the same error message appears in the console...
When I use the standard JavaFx components everything works nice

Information about the Java, I use:
I have already imported the JFoenix library into eclipse; 
I use jdk1.8.0_111;
I have the newest JFoenix jar

That's the error:

```html
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
 at application.Main.start(Main.java:26)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
 ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

My Main class:

```html
package application;
 
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class Main extends Application {
 
 private AnchorPane root;
 private Stage primaryStage;
 
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  try {
  
   this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
   this.primaryStage.setTitle("SimpleMySQLConnector - Login");
   
   FXMLLoader load;
   load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/LoginScreen.fxml"));
   root = load.load();
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
   
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
  
 }
}
```

```html
package application;
 
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class Main extends Application {
 
 private AnchorPane root;
 private Stage primaryStage;
 
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  try {
  
   this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
   this.primaryStage.setTitle("SimpleMySQLConnector - Login");
   
   FXMLLoader load;
   load = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/LoginScreen.fxml"));
   root = load.load();
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
   
  } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
  
 }
}
```

That's the fxml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1118.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="587.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="590.0" prefWidth="500.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0a52c9;">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#fafafa" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="156.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="282.0" promptText="Benutzername" unFocusColor="#3fd6f4">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXTextField>
            <JFXPasswordField focusColor="WHITE" layoutX="112.0" layoutY="279.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="282.0" promptText="Passwort" unFocusColor="#3fd6f4">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXPasswordField>
            <JFXButton layoutX="204.0" layoutY="375.0" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="91.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3fd6f4;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXCheckBox layoutX="159.0" layoutY="479.0" text="Angemeldet bleiben" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXCheckBox>
            <Label layoutX="188.0" layoutY="58.0" text="Login">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="50.0" />
               </font>
               <textFill>
                  <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#3fd6f4" />
                        <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </textFill>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="44.0" prefHeight="198.0" prefWidth="582.0" text="Willkommen bei" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="30.0" />
         </font>
         <textFill>
            <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
               <stops>
                  <Stop color="#00eade" />
                  <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
               </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
         </textFill>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="183.0" text="SimpleMySQLConnector">
         <textFill>
            <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
               <stops>
                  <Stop color="#02dbea" />
                  <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
               </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
         </textFill>
         <font>
            <Font size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I hope you're able to help me with these Information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your jdk to jdk 9 ver.

Answer (score 3):

İf you don't want to upgrade your jdk;

1.Change [Jfoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) version to 8.0.9 , if you use Java9&10 use v9.0.9.

2.Change AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" to

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.999-ea"
```

or

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
```

3.Change JavaFx [Scene Builder](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html#javafx-scenebuilder-2.0-oth-JPR) version according to the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade your jdk that is connected with your IDE to the current version don't use the old 1_8 version